# ArcGIS Portal instalation on the Windows OS?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-portal

I want to know if is it possible to install ArcGIS Portal on the Windows OS (other than Linux).

Can ArcGIS Portal be installed without ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  It is GIS SE policy to have only one question per Question.  Since Desktop is completely unrelated to the Server extension which implements Portal, I'd recommend you remove the second question.  Unfortunately, that will leave a very brief question which is answered by Esri's [system requiements documentation](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/install/windows/portal-for-arcgis-system-requirements.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can install it on a machine using Windows
http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/install/windows/welcome-to-the-portal-for-arcgis-installation-guide.htm

The machine does not need to be running ArcGIS Desktop
http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/install/windows/portal-for-arcgis-system-requirements.htm